# How to re-select the selected text in textarea by using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using javascript and jQuery to design a comment box.

My page has a `textarea` and 3 buttons (bold, underline and italic). If a user types text in the textarea, selects and clicks any button, the selected text should become *bold*, *underlined* or *italicised* (I have this functionality below).

My problem is that after clicking a button with text selected, although the html tags are correctly inserted, the selection is lost. That is, when I type: "Hello, I'm here.", select "I'm here" and click the *bold* button. **I'm here** becomes bold but if I want to also *underline* or *italicise*, I have to reselect the text.

So, my question is: How do I re-select the selected text in the `textarea`?

I tried `myTextarea.select()` but this code will select the entire contents of the `textarea`, not only the selected text.

**Update:**

Here is what I've got so far:

```
var mystring = ""; // default string

/* Bold event */
function Bold()
{
  var startString;
  var endString;
  var startPos; // starting position
  var endPos; // ending position
  var selectedText;
  var temp = document.getElementById("myTextarea");

  // check if text is selected
  if(temp.selectionStart !== undefined)
  {
    startPos = temp.selectionStart;
    endPos = temp.selectionEnd;
    selectedText = temp.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
    startString = temp.value.substring(0, startPos);
    endString = temp.value.substring(endPos, temp.value.length);
  }

  $("#myTextarea").val(startString + "[B]" + selectedText + "[/B]" + endString); // rewrite textarea value

  if(mystring !== "") // check if default string is NOT null, return null if it's the first clicked
  {
    mystring = mystring.replace(selectedText, "<b>" + selectedText + "</b>");
  }
  else
  {
    mystring = startString + "<b>" + selectedText + "</b>" + endString;
  }

  // write to preview panel
  $("#preview").html(mystring);
  $("#myTextarea").focus();
}
```

When I select "I'm here" in the `textarea` and click the bold button the code above will insert `[B]` and `[/B]` into the `textarea` and `<b>` tags into the preview panel.

Comment: You can use the `Selection/Range` API to read and modify the current selection. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Comment: If your in a textarea and your wanting to keep a select, I would imagine you could save off and reset this.selectionStart and this.selectionEnd.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement

Comment: If you still need help, show us what you have already done.

Comment: @jcuenod I have updated my question. Please read again and help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reselect the text you can do:

```
temp.setSelectionRange(startPos, endPos + 6);
```

I've added `+ 6` because you're inserting 6 new characters so I'm expanding the selection to include them. You could also add 3 to `startPos` and `endPos` (and let the characters wrap the selection) - IMO this is inferior UX wise.